How can I use Mypy with cookiecutter templates? Mypy throws "is not a valid Python package name" error
I have the following directory containing my files:
{{cookiecutter.project_name}}

I want to run mypy on this directory and all Python files above it (such as Cookiecutter hooks).
When I try to run mypy . I get:
{{cookiecutter.project_name}} is not a valid Python package name

Which to be fair is true, but are there no ways to get mypy to work with a cookiecutter template?

The solution here is to create an actual directory from that template, then run Mypy on that instead. Does that work for you?

You don’t have Python files. You have templates which cookiecutter uses to create Python files. You would need a plugin to allow mypy to operate directly on the templates.

Technically yes, except that we explicitly make all our cookiecutter files valid Python. Meaning that they can be type checked.
